# Python: 2.6:Trying to build a statement like exec('if' + varname + '< 1.0:')

Tags: python, if-statement, exec

My goal here is to have the same if statement in a for loop were the variable name changes
Those statements are in a function in a different file: the appropriate Import scheme 
as been set.

Examples:

```
for i in range(0,10):

    myvar = ''
    myvar = myvar + str(i)
    exec('if' + myvar + '< 0:')
`do something`
```

It say about the do something part "unexpected ident "
I remove the ident and it say; KeyError: 'myvar1'
I tried using this instead

```
if vars()[myvar] < 0:

    do something
```

It gives me the same  `KeyError: 'myvar1'`

Is there a way to make such a variable statement to work ?

Comment: What are you trying to do? Check if any number in 0 .. 10 is less than 0?

Comment: So the first one is broken because the exec scope isn't passed to the "do something", the next one is broken because you are checking if 'myvar1' is in your local vars, which it isn't, so you get a key error.  But ditto what KennyTM said...

Comment: @user1098589: I did my best and tried to correct formatting of your question, but seriously: think what you want to do and explain it correctly, then paste the code you have tried and format it accordingly (so it is displayed correctly, separated from the rest of the question). What you are trying to do requires enough effort to be understood, you do not need to make reading your question more complicated.

Comment: Forget you ever heard of eval.  You will be much better off not using it.

Answer (score 3):

You are passing the string "if 0 < 0:" to the exec() function. This is not a syntactically valid construct -- it's missing the controlled suite. You might consider instead:

```
if eval(myvar) < 0:
    do_something()
```

As a more general point, however, dynamic evaluation of variable names is almost invariably the wrong thing to do in a production program. You are usually better to use a dict to map keys to values (that's what they are for, and you avoid the use of exec() and eval()).

Answer (score 1):

So you should really just refactor your code to store myvarN as a list. Then you can just do:

```
for element in myvars:
    if element < 0:
        doSomething(element)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to do something like this:

```
var1 = 10
var2 = 12
var3 = 18

for i in range(10):
  if locals().get('var%d' % i, 0) > 10:
    # something here for the conditions that pass.
```

That code should work.  The biggest difference from what you'd done is that I called `.get()` on `locals()` so that if you try to test a non-existent variable it comes back with something.  This ... is an odd approach, tbh, but sometimes odd approaches are necessary.